# Não consigo partir as linhas no corpo do email. O texto sai corrido

Tags: html

Este código cria um link que abre uma pagina de email com o assunto e com o corpo da mensagem configurados.
O meu problema é que não consigo partir as linhas no corpo da mensagem. Tentei as varias indicações que encontrei e o texto sai sempre corrido.
Agradeço ajuda.

Corpo e assunto preenchido:

```
<a href="mailto:xxxxx@xxxx.com?body=Não consigo partir esta linha.&subject=Pedido de Informações"> E-mail </a>
```

Comment: qual é o código? Consulte a maneira de  [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JoãoCarneiro Primeiro, você não incluiu o código. Edite sua pergunta incluindo ele e explicando o que você quer dizer com partir as linhas no corpo da mensagem. Quais indicações você tentou?

Comment: <a href="mailto:xxxxx@xxxx.com?body=Não consigo partir esta linha.&subject=Pedido de Informações"> E-mail </a>

Comment: Sim, indiquei mas ficou meio escondido. Pretendo crias várias linhas de texto no corpo da mensagem do email. O problema é que o texto aparece corrido. Não deixa partir linhas ou criar paragrafos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o hexa `%0D` que é equivalente ao <kbd>Enter</kbd> (*carriage return*) na [tabela ASCII](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/cfg_fund/command/reference/cfnapph.html).

```
                                                      ↓
<a href="mailto:xxxxx@xxxx.com?body=Não consigo partir%0Desta linha.&subject=Pedido de Informações"> E-mail </a>
```

Isso irá fazer uma quebra de linha na posição que você quiser.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Muito obrigado. abraço

Comment: @JoãoCarneiro Não seja por isso amigo. Se achou útil a resposta, marque  ✓. Grande abraço!